# How to align two buttons in the middle with a certain margin in html

Tags: html, css, button, center

I am trying to align two buttons in the middle of the screen in HTML. When I try using `text-align: center;` it is not working. Below is my code for the button.

```
<style>

.button {
      margin-top: 15px;
      background-color: #0066FF;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
 }

 <body>

 <div class="floated run">
 <form action="aboutus.html">
 <button class="button">See Projects</button>
 </form>
 </div>

 <div class="floated run">
 <form action="end.html">
 <button class="button">About Us</button>
 </form>
 </div>

 </body>
```

I am aware there are multiple answers to this question, but none of them have helped me so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use Flexbox to get what you what and slightly change your markup.

So you'll need a wrapper with `.flex` class, and children with `.flex-item` classes.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item + .flex-item {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #0066FF;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <form action="aboutus.html" class="flex-item">
    <button class="button">See Projects</button>
  </form>

  <form action="end.html" class="flex-item">
    <button class="button">About Us</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help but for some reason when I insert this their is a huge margin underneath the buttons where a div was supposed to go

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is that because you have the buttons inside divs and forms, any CSS you apply directly to the buttons will not work - you will need to position the divs first:

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6967/

The essence of this example is this CSS:

```
.floated {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
}

.first {
  text-align: right;
}
```

With this HTML:

```
<div class="floated run first">
 <form action="aboutus.html">
 <button class="button">See Projects</button>
 </form>
 </div>

 <div class="floated run">
 <form action="end.html">
 <button class="button">About Us</button>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Note that I have added a class `.first` to the first div.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why are their two floated classes above?

Comment: Because I was too hasty.  :) I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I will run the answer on my code and then mark it as right

Comment: For the record, I see no reason in this context why you would need the `form` tags - buttons can exist outside of forms, unless you plan to add search or input elements. Your original solution of `text-align: center` would most likely work if the buttons were in a single div.

Comment: I figured that. Can you input that into the question above. It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: No - the above answer is the correct answer to your question. My previous comment is merely a suggestion based on my assumption about your code. It's important that future searches for this issue do not result in inaccurate or presumptuous answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can float your button to left, add a little left margin, wrap it with one `div`, and than position it to center:

```html
<style>

    .button {
          margin-top: 15px;
          margin-left: 10px;
          background-color: #0066FF;
          border: none;
          color: white;
          padding: 10px 20px;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          float: left;
          font-size: 16px;
          cursor: pointer;
     }

     .button-wrapper{
          width: 55%;
          margin: 0 auto;
     }

 </style>
     <body>
     <div class="button-wrapper">
     <div class="floated run">
     <form action="aboutus.html">
     <button class="button">See Projects</button>
     </form>
     </div>

     <div class="floated run">
     <form action="end.html">
     <button class="button">About Us</button>
     </form>
     </div>
     </div>
     </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy

Give a div.floated width:100% and text-align:center

check - 
  `div.floated {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}`